# Can't stay logged in and/or log into Site-specific Metas

Tags: support, bug

Using Windows 7, Firefox 27.0.1, on a computer that I've definitely been able to log onto Meta's before.

I'm a moderator over on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/), but I'm not logged in on Arqade's Meta site, and can't appear to do so, either.

Wait, scratch that, I'm logged in... and, scratch that again, when I opened the question I've been trying to close as a duplicate, I'm logged out again.

Clicking "Log In" takes me to the parent site's log-in page (where I am already logged in). Clicking through the Log In routine (using Google) successfully takes me back to the Arqade Meta page I was at... but fails to actually log me in.

Clicking "Sign Up with Google" takes me to a 404.

I am stumped. (And even more confused because it's only happening on my home PC, but not my work or personal laptops) Any help?

And yeah, no problems logging into Meta.Stackoverflow, either...

Comment: Have you done the usual - clear cache, etc? Since you're using Firefox, I also recommend trying to clear browsing history. For some reason, Firefox just once in a while does this.

Comment: @AnnaLear Clearing the cache has provided some solace. I got the question closed, finally. ;D

Comment: @RavenDreamer http://shouldiblamecaching.com/